# Erdos' Arithmetic Progression of Polignac's Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Paul Erdos has proven that there is an infinite arithmetic progression of Polignac's numbers - odd numbers that cannot be represented as a sum of a prime and a power of $2$, in [Erdos, Paul. "On integers of the form $2^k + p$ and some related problems." (Summa Brasil. Math 2 (1950): 113-123.)](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf)

What is the explicit form ($a + b n$) of this arithmetic progression?
This [web site](http://www.bitman.name/math/article/388) seems to give the answer:

$$2^{241} \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 13 \times 241 \times n + 1622548664997933681386229593857244360639853287017787157811814622833051518894081$$

without references, and it is not clear how the solution was derived.
I checked and found that the large integer is $459165 \times 2^{241} + 1$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You've picked an interesting topic for your first Question.  A couple of suggestions for improvements.  First, you can use mathematical expressions in your posts using $\LaTeX$ thanks to [MathJax software](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Second, the crucial details of your Question are presented only as a link to another website.  It might disappear and make your Question unintelligible to Readers.   Better to quote and/or paraphrase the most important material at that link in your post, and then the link can likely be reconstructed should things change.

Comment: I went ahead with the first part of hardmath's suggestion as it's no problem for me, but the second part is something that has to be done by *you*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the paper itself, page 8 of the link you gave:

> Proof of Theorem 3. Clearly every integer satisfies at least one of the following congruences: $0(mod 2),0(mod 3),1(mod 4),3(mod 8),7(mod 12),23(mod 24)$. Therefore, if x is congruent to: $1(mod 2), 1(mod 7), 2(mod 5), 2^3(mod 17), 2^7(mod 13), 2^{23}(mod 241)$,
> then for any k, $x-2^k$ is a multiple of one of the primes $3,5,7,13,17,241$. This proves theorem $3$.

The reason this works is Zsigmondy's theorem (there exists $p\mid2^n-1,p\nmid2^m-1$ for $m<n$ if $n\neq6$). These congruences can be converted into the form $a+bn$ by Chinese remainder theorem. The paper itself doesn't mention $2^{241}$ anywhere.